# ANSI escape codes on input line in Powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, wine, ansi-escape

Hi I have a specific usage. I am running Powershell (v7.1.0) under Wine(v5.22) on Manjaro Linux(Kernel: 5.9.11).

The command line in Powershell is showing ANSI escape color codes (as shown in the image). Is there any way to disable it completely?

[image: In the image, I have typed WORD which is enclosed with ANSI codes automatically]

In the image, I have typed `WORD` which is enclosed with ANSI codes automatically. The codes appear as soon as I type anything.

Comment: PowerShell supports Linux natively, why do you run it under wine?

Comment: Actually, I am running some software (windows-compatible only) under wine and for testing purposes, I needed Powershell.

Comment: PowerShell is a *shell* and not a terminal so it knows nothing about ANSI sequence. It just passes the whole text stream to the terminal (which is conhost.exe by default on newer Windows). `conhost.exe` understands how to treat ANSI sequence but apparently wine's doesn't. You need to tell the running app to not emit ANSI sequence, or use a capable terminal

Comment: You can use some other console terminal instead, for example ConEmu, which can run CMD and PowerShell flawlessly, with colors texts